# Android get actual instance of a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity with a `Navigation Drawer` that loads different fragments in a `RelativeLayout`. The main activity also has a toolbar with filter button. I want to sort the items that are in the `Fragment` loaded, but the filter button is in the activity, so it throws me `NullPointerException` when i call `MainScreenFragment main = new MainScreenFragment()`. I would like to know if there is any way to get the actual instance of the current fragment, and not creating a new instance, to avoid the NullPointerException. The method i'm calling is `Task(muscle);` in the `Activity`. Hope you can help.

PS: I already checked all the options here but no one has solved my problem

**MainScreenActivity.java**

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager view;
    private SimpleTabAdapter adapter;
    private Button songs;
    private String email,name;
    private int id;
    private TextView emailView, nameView, Username, title;
    private ImageButton settings;
    private MySQLiteHelper database;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    public ImageView Sort;
    private CharSequence activityTitle;
    private CharSequence itemTitle;
    private String[] tagTitles;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String muscle = "ALL";
    public Spinner spinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        tagTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_array);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.bringToFront();
        Sort = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Sort);

        ArrayList<DrawerItem> items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        items.add(new DrawerItem(tagTitles[0],R.mipmap.home));
        items.add(new DrawerItem(tagTitles[1],R.mipmap.acrobatics));
        items.add(new DrawerItem(tagTitles[2],R.mipmap.profile));

        drawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, items));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Crear ActionBarDrawerToggle para la apertura y cierre
//        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        toolbar.setTitle("Home");
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)){
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
                }
                else
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

        Sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this)
                        .title(R.string.filtertitle)
                        .items(R.array.filter_items)
                        .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                                if (which != -1){

                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        })
                        .positiveText(R.string.choose)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* La escucha del ListView en el Drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Reemplazar el contenido del layout principal por un fragmento
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new MainFragment();
                Sort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new WorkoutsFragment();
                Sort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolbar.setTitle("My Workouts");
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                Sort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                break;
        }

        // Se actualiza el item seleccionado y el título, después de cerrar el drawer
        drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(tagTitles[position]);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }

    /* Método auxiliar para setear el titulo de la action bar */
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        itemTitle = title;
//        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(itemTitle);
    }
    public void WorkoutActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void toast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private String email;
    private String name;
    public TwoWayView recyclerView;
    private Button songs;
    public static JsonWorkout[] Workouts;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String muscle = "ALL";
    public Toolbar myToolbar;


    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fmain, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        if (myToolbar != null)
//            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        recyclerView = (TwoWayView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
        email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        if (CheckInternet(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
            Task(muscle);
        }
        else{
            toast("Please check your internet conection.");
        }
//        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
//
//        spinnerArray.add("ALL");
//        spinnerArray.add("ABS/CORE");
//        spinnerArray.add("UPPER BODY");
//        spinnerArray.add("LOWER BODY");
//
//        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_secondary,spinnerArray);
//
//        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
//
//        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
//                String element = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
//                muscle = element;
//                Task(muscle);
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
//
//            }
//        });

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        // Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Your code to refresh the list here.
                // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
                // once the network request has completed successfully.
                if (CheckInternet(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
                    Task(muscle);
                }
                else{
                    toast("Please check your internet conection.");
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });
        // Configure the refreshing colors
        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);


    }

    public void Task(final String muscle){

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Customize the request
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .header("Authorization", "auth-token")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();

                okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                Log.v("Response",response.toString());
                // Customize or return the response
                return response;
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://api.silverbarsapp.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        SilverbarsService service = retrofit.create(SilverbarsService.class);
        Call<JsonWorkout[]> call = service.getWorkouts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonWorkout[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonWorkout[]> call, Response<JsonWorkout[]> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Workouts = null;
//                    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                    if (Objects.equals(muscle,"ALL")){
                        Workouts = response.body();
                    }
                    else{
                        JsonWorkout[] auxWorkout = response.body();
                        int x = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < auxWorkout.length; i++){
                            String muscleData = auxWorkout[i].getMain_muscle();
                            if (Objects.equals(muscle, muscleData)){
                                Workouts[x] = auxWorkout[i];
                                x++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new WorkoutAdapter(getActivity()));
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors yourself
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    Log.v("Error",errorBody.toString());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonWorkout[]> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("Exception",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You can get the actual fragment instance through the fragment backstack. Do you know how to use it or would you like me to post a detailed answer?

Comment: a detailed answer please

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: You could use findFragmentByTag https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

Comment: So from MainScreenActivity you are trying to call a function inside MainFragment? Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get an instance of the currently loaded fragment, you can override the `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` interface thus:

First get an instance of the `FragmentManager`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Next, in your `selectItem` method, replace the fragments in the following way instead of doing `fragment = new MainFragment()` etc (since I am unsure of the name of the container layout you are using to inflate the fragment, I'll call it `fragment_container`):

```
switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment(), null)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            Sort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setTitle("Home");
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new WorkoutsFragment(), null)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            Sort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setTitle("My Workouts");
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment(), null)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            Sort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
            break;
    }
```

Next, attach an `OnBackStackChangedListener` thus:

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if (currentFragment instanceof MainFragment) {
                //place your filtering logic here using currentFragment
            }
         }
  }
```

Do let me know if you need further help.

Comment: it work perfectly, thanks a lot, i just made a little change in the fragment call, i just call the current fragment in another listener

Comment: Glad I was able to nudge you in the right direction. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if i understand you, but you can get your Fragments with

```
List<Fragments> fragments = getActivity().getFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

Comment: simple, i want to trigger a background task of a fragment from its parent activity